# How can I convert a left table into a summary table?

Tags: python, pandas

How do I convert table left to summary table right?

[image: Screenshot]

I tried using get dummies function to convert values to 0 and 1.
I don't know how to proceed after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
col1 = ['']+['Hampshire']*8+['']+['Hampshire']+['']+['Hampshire']+['','']+['Hampshire']*4
col2 = ['Southhampton'] + ['']*12 + ['Southhampton']*2 + ['']*4
col3 = ['']*11 + ['Isle of wight'] + ['']*7
col4 = ['Met']*5 + [''] + ['Met']*13
col5 = ['']*5 + ['Partially met'] + ['']*13
col6 = ['']*19

df = pd.DataFrame(data = dict(zip(['Hampshire', 'Southhampton', 'Isle of wight', '5met', '5partially met', '5Not met'],[col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6])))
df = df.replace('', np.nan)
df['Hampshire'] = df['Hampshire'].fillna(df['Southhampton'])
df['Hampshire'] = df['Hampshire'].fillna(df['Isle of wight'])
df[['Hampshire','5met','5partially met', '5Not met']].groupby(by=['Hampshire']).count()
```

I had to generate the data for you (since you didn't post any besides the image), but I think this get's the job done. I hope this helps.

Comment: OMG! You are so clever!! Thank you so much! All makes sense.

Comment: No worries, accept my answer then XD

Answer (score 0):

Using a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) after reshaping the two blocks of columns with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
s1 = df[['Hampshire', 'Southhampton', 'Isle of wight']].stack().droplevel(-1)
s2 = df[['5met', '5partially met']].stack().droplevel(-1)

out = (pd.crosstab(s1, s2)
         .reindex(columns=['Met', 'Partially met', 'Not met'], fill_value=0)
         .rename_axis(columns=None, index=None)
       )
```

Output:

```
               Met  Partially met  Not met
Hampshire       13              1        0
Isle of wight    1              0        0
Southhampton     3              0        0
```